# Associating entities, not creating, with many-to-many relationships in EF Code First MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, c#-4.0, ef-code-first, dbcontext

In MVC3 Code First EF how do you associate one entity with another without creating a new one (many-to-many)?

So I have a many-to-many relationship between class1 and class2. I need class1 to hold many class2 and vice versa. However, class2 is independent; I have a list of them that I want to edit separately and then associate with a new class1.

When I pass my class2List to the controller( via AJAX and JSON), I checked and all the Ids of the class2s correspond to existing ids in the db, i.e. new class2s are not created.

**Model**

```
class
{
   [key]
   public int Id {set; get;} 
}
class1 : class 
{
        private ICollection<class2> _class2s;
        public virtual ICollection<class2> class2s
        {
            get { return _class2s ?? ( _class2s = new HashSet<class2>()); }
            set { _class2s = value; }
        }  
}

class2 : class
{
        private ICollection<class1> _class1s;
        public virtual ICollection<class1> class1s
        {
            get { return _class1s ?? ( _class1s = new HashSet<class1>()); }
            set { _class1s = value; }
        }  
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult SaveChanges(List<class2> class2List)
    {
        createNewClass2AndAssociateExistingClass2s(class2List);
        SaveChangesToDb();
        return View("ProductDetail", Model);
    }

createNewClass2AndAssociateExistingClass2s(List<class2> class2List)
{
    var newClass1 = newClass1()
    {
      class2s = class2List;
    }

    ////UnitOfWork allows me to access several DbSets in one transaction
    unitOfWork.Create(newClass1) 

}
SaveChangesToDb()
{
    unitOfWork.Commit();
}
```

What this does is create a new class1 (as it should) but instead of associating the existing class2s with it, it makes new class2s with new Ids and adds them to the database.

**My question:**

Does this have to do with how EF is reading my Id property from base class?

How would I be able to associate several existing class2s as a list with a new class1, without creating new class2s in the database?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so two things I learned from figuring this out:

- I was inheriting from an abstract class when I should have been implementing an interface. This is a great idea if you have several entities that have a similar property such as "Id" and you want to do something like

  `T FindById<T>(int id) where T : IEntity`
- When making associations in EF, even if the Id matches an existing entry, it will not update that entry, unless EF is tracking that entry in the context, [as it says here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/29/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-4-add-attach-and-entity-states.aspx). What I needed to do was:

  - Add a method in the mapping layer that gets the entry by id that I
    want from the repository
  - Copy the attributes of the new entry into that context entry
  - Return the context entry

Hope this helps someone